# Tengo dudas en unas consultas

Tags: sql, pgadmin

hola tengo dudas en unas consultas de sql soy muy malo para ese tema tengo que hacer 5 consultas en pgadmin el cual
Obtener el nombre de los colegiados que han participado en menos de tres partidos
Obtener el nombre de los jugadores que han participado en menos de tres partidos.
Obtener el nombre del equipo que tiene el mayor número de jugadores.
Obtener el nombre de los jugadores que tienen edad mayor al promedio general de edad.
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

script tablas

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPO(
IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO INTEGER,
    NOMBRE_EQUIPO VARCHAR(30),
    PAIS VARCHAR(30),
    CIUDAD VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_PRIMARIA_EQUIPO PRIMARY KEY(IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO)

);

CREATE TABLE JUGADOR(
    IDENTIFICADOR_JUGADOR INTEGER,
    NOMBRE_JUGADOR VARCHAR(30),
    EDAD INTEGER,
    NACIONALIDAD VARCHAR(30),
    IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_PRIMARIA_JUGADOR PRIMARY KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_JUGADOR),
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_FORANEA_EQUIPO FOREIGN KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO)
    REFERENCES EQUIPO(IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE PARTIDO(
    IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO INTEGER,
    FECHA DATE,
    HORA VARCHAR(6),
    ESTADIO VARCHAR(30),
    JORNADA INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ID_EQUIPO_LOCAL INTEGER,
    ID_EQUIPO_VISITANTE INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_PRIMARIA_PARTIDO PRIMARY KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO),
    CONSTRAINT CF_EQUIPO_LOCAL FOREIGN KEY(ID_EQUIPO_LOCAL)
        REFERENCES EQUIPO(IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT CF_EQUIPO_VISITANTE FOREIGN KEY (ID_EQUIPO_VISITANTE)
    REFERENCES EQUIPO (IDENTIFICADOR_EQUIPO)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE PARTIDO_COLEGIADO(
IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO INTEGER,
    IDENTIFICADOR_COLEGIADO INTEGER,
    PUESTO VARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_PRIMARIA_PC PRIMARY KEY(IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO,IDENTIFICADOR_COLEGIADO),
    CONSTRAINT CF_PARTIDO FOREIGN KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO)
    REFERENCES PARTIDO (IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT CF_COLEGIADO FOREIGN KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_COLEGIADO)
    REFERENCES COLEGIADO (IDENTIFICADOR_COLEGIADO)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE JUGADOR_PARTIDO(
    IDENTIFICADOR_JUGADOR INTEGER,
    IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO INTEGER,
    PUESTO VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_PRIMARIA_JUGADOR_PARTIDO PRIMARY KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_JUGADOR,IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO),
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_FORANEA_JUGADOR FOREIGN KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_JUGADOR)
    REFERENCES JUGADOR (IDENTIFICADOR_JUGADOR)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT CLAVE_FORANEA_PARTIDO FOREIGN KEY (IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO)
    REFERENCES PARTIDO (IDENTIFICADOR_PARTIDO)
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que llevas al momento hecho, dudas puntuales y unos datos de prueba para poder replicar tu ejercicio

Comment: para la consulta obtener el nombre del equipo que tiene el mayor numero de jugadores tengo mas o menos mi consulta asi:     SELECT j.nombre_equipo  FROM equipo as j, jugador as e WHERE j.identificador_equipo=e.identificador jugador BOOL e.identificador_equipo GROUP  BY nombre_jugador